# Filter nested multiple list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the below class data in c#. below is the json format for the same.

```
{
   "Data": {
      "plans": [
         {
            "pDecision": "E",
            "pNumber": 123,
            "car": [
               {
                  "iNumber": 1,
                  "liList": [
                     {
                        "CID": 112658799,
                        "liDecision": "A"
                     },
                     {
                        "CID": 112658800,
                        "liDecision": "A"
                     }
                  ]
               },
               {
                  "iNumber": 2,
                  "liList": [
                     {
                        "CID": 1,
                        "liDecision": "E"
                     },
                     {
                        "CID": 2,
                        "liDecision": "A"
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to get the details of car and plan. Car object should filter with
"CID": 1 and "liDecision": "E". tried using any but its returing all fields. Since this is collection
Data.plan.where(p=>p.car.any(c=>c.lilist.any(l=>l.cid==1 && l.lidecesion=="E"))); tried this one.
 any help?

Comment: I can see your problem, you dont have any code... just a lump of json and a wish. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Where` returns an enumerable of plans, not cars, and your plan instance contains two cars. If you want to filter cars you need to apply your `Where` to cars collection

```
Data.plans.SelectMany(p => p.car)
.Where(c => c.lilist.Any( li => li.cid==1 && li.lidecesion=="E"));
```

if you also need a plan that contains that car

```
Data.plans.SelectMany(p => p.car.Select(c => new {Car = c, Plan = p})) // this returns cars with according plans
.Where(x => x.Car.lilist.Any(li => li.cid==1 && li.lidecesion=="E"));
```

You will get objects-pairs { Car, Plan }, Plan property will still have the full collection of cars, but Car should satisfy your filter.

Comment: The solution is good ... but it seems to be more efficient to **first filter the cars**, _**before**_ generating the auxiliaries Car/Plan objects, avoiding generating unused objects:  
`
Data.plans.SelectMany(p => p.car.Where(x => x.Car.lilist.Any(li => li.cid==1 && li.lidecesion=="E")).Select(c => new {Car = c; Plan = p}));
`

Comment: @CicheR, Agree, you version is more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for mentioning what you have already tried :-). May be you can add it to the original question then keeping as a comment ???

You have nested lists and one approach would be to flatten them out and then filter on the flat results

Consider the following code, it first flats Plans then LiLists and finally does the filtering on result

`var plans = carPlans.Data.Plans.SelectMany(plan => plan.Car)
            .SelectMany(e => e.LiList).Where(list => list.Cid == 1 && list.LiDecision == "E");`

Hope this helps

Good luck